# ms-access 2003: form does not open! help!

Tags: ms-access

i have an access db with forms, one of the forms is not opening. i double clicked on it, i tried to open in design mode. nothing happens. there's no error message, but nothing happens.

has anyone had this issue before?

i am sorry i actually am getting an error now:

The error said that there wasn't enough memory to open it or something to that effect.

Comment: Can you open the table or query that the form gets its data from?

Comment: Do you have any code in the OnLoad event?

Comment: no i do not have any code on onload

Comment: Have you done a compact and repair?

Comment: no i have not. but what we do to mitigate this error is we make a copy of the file and when the new one stops working we use the old one. i tried to export the form that was not opening at all to a different database and it would not export at all, no error again

Comment: Have you written the bad form to a text file, copied all the other objects to a new database and then imported the bad form from text?

Comment: Can you open it in DESIGN VIEW and then switch to FORM VIEW?

Comment: neither design view nor form view work. i try to open it but it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lack of an error message makes this extra challenging.  OTOH, without an error message, how do you know the form hasn't opened?  Could it be open but hidden?

Try these two commands in the Immediate Window:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "YourForm", acNormal,,,,acWindowNormal

? Forms("YourForm").Name
```

Do you you get any error messages then?  If so, tell us what error messages and at which step they occur.

Comment: i am sorry i actually am getting an error now:

The error said that there wasn't enough memory to open it or something to that effect.

Comment: Nuts.  I hoped you would get an error message I knew what to do with.  I can only fall back to 2 generic suggestions without much hope they will help: check your project's references; try decompile.

Comment: "Not enough memory" usually means corruption somewhere in the VBA project. A backup/decompile/recompile cycle is in order.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the bible for Access corruption issues.

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm

First things first: try to decompile and recompile (check the help files on how to do that).  Next, try creating a second database and importing your form from the corrupt one.  Lastly, use SaveAsText and LoadFromText to export and reimport the form.

Comment: I wrote a script to automate the process of decompiling a database: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20666309/1399438