# When I save a form in structure view and then I open back in form view, it gets me an error. Each new file the same

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I get the "There isn't enought memory to perform this operation. Please close unneeded programs and try again."
The only thing I do and I can recreate the problem:
I open the form, it works!
I open in structure view, I delete a label. I save. I open the form! Puf ERROR!

I have 4GB of ram and only 1,5GB occupied...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a situation like that once, and the only cure I found was to decompile the application.  Decompile discards all the compiled code, and gives you an opportunity re-compile your application's source code anew.  That will allow you to overcome a situation where the existing compiled code has become corrupted.

It's not a terribly difficult process.  Fortunately, @David-W-Fenton described it in clear detail in a previous Stack Overflow answer: [HOW TO decompile and recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/ms-access-how-to-decompile-and-recompile/3268188#3268188)

Also read what Tony Toews says about Access database corruption: [Corrupt Microsoft Access MDBs FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm)