# Access 2010 on shared server compile troubles

Tags: windows, ms-access, windows-7, ms-access-2010

I have a access 2012 application that works just fine until my counterpart across town tries to run it.  We share a server.  When I compile it, he can't run it.  When he compiles it, the roles are reversed.  He can run it, but I can't.  Version of Access is the same.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you add any library references?

Comment: I checked the reference on the two machines and the settings were identical. This really has me scratching my head. I feel I am missing something fairly trivial.

Comment: You both have all the updates installed yesno? Do you both have the same sort order set (I am not sure it matters in this case, but it might)?

Answer (score 2):

#### Determine the faulty system

First, you should test each compiled version on other machines to find out which of you or your colleague is likely to be the source of the issue.

If you have isolated a single particular machine where the issue originate, it may be a good thing to just uninstall Office completely and re-install it clean; something else might have been corrupted.

#### Shared database

When you say *shared server*, I hope that you are not running your Access database from a shared network folder, but instead properly split it into a backend database (that contains data and is located in a shared network folder) and a front-end database (that contains forms and reports and is run on each user's machine).
If you are allowing users to run the `.accde` file from a network folder, [stop right now and split your database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx)!

#### Things to check

Best to disable your Antivirus while you check. It could be blocking some calls or access to some libraries:

- Systems with different OS or MSOffice bitness (32bit vs. 64bit).
  There are issues with using [Win32 APIs on 64bit MS Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264421.aspx).
  If you reference older external controls on your forms made for 32 bit, [they won't work on a 64 bit machine](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitproprevious/thread/e4ec9cc7-b621-4122-9d8d-ed4d7cfb6e0d).
- Machines with slightly different MSOffice patch levels. There were definitely issues like this a [few months ago with SP1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/access-2010-sp1-you-receive-random-crashes-in/d2bf6175-075a-4a12-a2b1-f55d40af271b?page=17) until a [fix was issued](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2011/office-2010-sp1-and-access-2010-runtime-sp1-are-broken/).
  Check your MSAccess exact version: Menu File > Help.
  Mine says *Version: 14.0.6123.5001 (32 bit)*
- References to external libraries (or other `accda/mda`) that are of different versions or locations and can't be found on the system.
  This can be complicated to track and solve, but there are [pointers on how to minimize the issues](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/accessdev/thread/4ea21b58-2881-478b-9e9a-f58adf03ce6c).
  Are you referencing any library that is located by an absolute path?
- Somewhat related, use of 3rd-party ActiveX components that are not properly registered, or not exactly the same version on each machine.
- Subtle corruption of the database.
  Try to [decompile it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/ms-access-how-to-decompile-and-recompile) (after making a backup).
- Are you using linked tables against a backend database that is at a different location on each machine?
- Make sure that the folder from which you run the compiled `accde` file is added to the list of [Trusted Locations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-HA010031999.aspx#BM11).
- Use the normal `addcb` database and run it in Runtime mode (using msaccess.exe [command line](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207) option `/runtime`).
  Are you getting the same issue?
- If the issue is coming from your code rather than a crash within access, it may be worth adding some logging to trace the execution of the code.
  You should also have a look at [vbWatchdog](http://www.everythingaccess.com/vbwatchdog.htm), and excellent library to manage errors and trace your code (you can try it for free).
  Highly recommended!