# How to click through Access Report using SendKeys

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

After having slogged through creating a table of contents for my access report, I have finally gotten to the point where the code works, and a table of contents is created.

As the [instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210269) from Microsoft state, I need to manually click through the Print Preview until the last page so that the TOC is created. This works.

**How can I click through the Access Report using SendKeys?**

Here is my code so far... it works perfectly, except that SendKeys does nothing!

```
'Click through report so that TOC code is executed
Dim rptCurReport As Report
Set rptCurReport = Screen.ActiveReport

With rptCurReport
    Application.DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "rptFundSelectionList"
    .Visible = True 'switch to false once code is ok
    'go through all pages
    For i = 1 To .Pages
        SendKeys "{PGDN}", True
    Next i

    'DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptFundSelectionList"
End With
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the methods of this specific case but I'd advise against using `SendKeys`. There can be multiple issues. If you run the code until the `.Visible = True` and it does nothing, then your selection didn't work out. Your `SendKeys` may have been performed multiple times before the page loading, in which case it does *something*, but not much.

Comment: Since the manual mentions *why* you have to scroll through, I'd try *selecting all records* via other means.

Comment: I can run the code until `.Visible = True` and if I switch it to False it works as well (this is also how I know I have the correct focus). Any suggestions on how to go through the records while I have the report open? I haven't any examples of that yet.

Comment: Ok. So using the SendKeys Method created a whole different set of issues as I documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932743/file-not-found-at-the-execution-of-any-vba-code-in-access-2007

Comment: I'm attempting to find a different way to step through the report... so I think your approach is correct user3819867

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to finally solve this issue for myself. Here is the code. May it help some other poor soul!

```
'Open report containing code to create TOC with list of ISINs from above
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFundSelectionList", acViewPreview, , strWhere
Set dict = Nothing

'Click through report so that TOC code is executed
Dim rptCurReport As Report
Set rptCurReport = Screen.ActiveReport

With rptCurReport
    Application.DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, .Name
    .Visible = True 'switch to false once code is ok
    'go through all pages
    SendKeys "{End}", True
    DoEvents
    Application.DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, .Name
    DoCmd.Close acReport, .Name, acSaveNo
End With
```