# Typo doesn't trigger error handling in Acess VBA

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, ms-access-2007, vba

After recently adding some new VBA code that referred to a control, my code wouldn't run. On investigation, I found the problem was a typo in the code referring to the control: I'd typed it as **Me.CheckYearEmd** (with an m) rather than **Me.CheckYearEnd**.

This is now resolved and the code's working fine, but the weird thing is the error didn't trigger my error handling; it just didn't run. My error handling works on a very simple basis:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

... 'Rest of sub

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox "The database has generated an error. Please contact the database administrator, quoting the following error message: '" & Err.Description & "'", vbCritical, "Database Error"
```

Is there something specific about referring to a control that doesn't exist (as I effectivley did above) that causes it to bypass error handling, and is there a way of catching these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't recreate the situation you described.  When I misspell a control name in the form's code, running Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu triggers a compile error: *"Method or data member not found"*.

However, if I don't run Debug->Compile and just try to run the form's procedure with the misspelled name, I still get that compile error.

Although I can't duplicate your situation, I'll offer a guess why the procedure's error handler doesn't catch it.  The directive, `On Error GoTo ErrHandler`, traps run-time errors.  But the misspelled control name triggers a compile error.

Comment: +1 I tested and got a compile error, too. Perhaps @BFDatabaseAdmin should consider a [/decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/2144390)?