# Error 53 File not found

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access 2003 DB, which has a VBA module. The module function points to an Excel file.

The function is calling the Excel file through the command line like this:
`Shell "Excel \\server\dir\filename.xls", vbMaximizedFocus`

The DB opens, the function gets triggered, and I get `Run-timer error '53': File not found`

I know that the Excel file exists, and I am able to open it. I have the security permissions to be able to access folders in the filepath.

**What I already tried:**

decompile+compact+recompile the DB, [using the instructions here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/ms-access-how-to-decompile-and-recompile)

I am still getting the same error. Can anyone suggest other causes/solutions?

**minor edit** - content remains the same.

Comment: Are you able to access the file `\\server\dir\filename.xls` from a file explorer window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the file not found error.  I adapted your code as follows, but it opens the workbook file without error.

```vb
Const cstrFile = "\\HP64\share\Access\temp.xls"
If Len(Dir(cstrFile)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "File '" & cstrFile & "' not found."
Else
    Shell "Excel " & cstrFile, vbMaximizedFocus
End If
```

Alternatively, you could create an Excel application instance and then open the file.  However I'm skeptical whether that would avoid the not found error.

```vb
Dim objExcel As Object 'Excel.Application
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Open cstrFile

' do stuff here
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the mapped network drive (letter). Check your immediate window:

```
?dir("N:/dir\filename.xls")
```

You can also open a workbook as follows (if you want more flexibility):

```
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oExcel.visible = true
oExcel.Workbooks.Open ("\\server\dir\filename.xls")

oExcel.Quit 'close
```

Comment: What was ultimately the reason for the path not being recognized?

Comment: for some reason, typing 'excel' into the shell would not launch excel. but if i entered the full path of excel.exe, it was able to launch. since the path might be different on different machines, and to account for future software upgrades, i decided to just call the excel object.