# access hangs on all new queries created

Tags: ms-access

Recently I am not able to run queries from my Access either 2002 or 2010 (Both installed on my laptop).
When I try to execute any query , even simple ones , Access hangs and then not responding.

Comment: On all databases, or just one in particular? Corrupt db, maybe?

Comment: I already tried compact and repair.Didn't try it on other databases

Comment: Try other dbs. If issue persists, reboot and try again. If still persists, reinstall Access/Office (especially if you've recently installed new software).

Comment: I have to ask - are the databases on a network or anything? You said Access is installed on your computer, but I'm not sure about the location of the actual database files.

Comment: same problem on all dbs.Reinstalling office didn't help.All dbs are on my local drive.

Comment: Try the reverse -- if you take your db to a different box, does Access happily execute the query? If so, something on your box is trashed and (if possible) you need to call in IT services. It very much sounds like you're going to find out that your box is the problem, not the db (which, I suppose, is a good thing.)

Comment: After testing dbs on other machines , they work fine, but I noticed the following: on my laptop queries are fine with local tables but the queries which hangs are connected to Linked tables from SQL. These tables CAN be opened normally from my access db.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are other processes that might be consuming all your machine's CPU/RAM:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ie/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Also, did you try to create a new database, populate a test table with some test data and run a simple SELECT statement to see what happens? Did you try to open this database in another machine?

Did you try to turn it off and on again? :)

Comment: db working fine on other machines.But all dbs have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Try compact and repair the db.
2. If it still does not help try to uncompile the db. (see: [How does one decompile and recompile a database application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3266849/880990))
3. Type Alt-F11 (opens VBA), go to menu *Tools > References*, check if there are faulty references and repair them if necessary.
4. If it does not help try importing the faulty db objects into a new empty db.
5. For Access 2002 (I don't know for 2010) execute menu *Help > Detect and repair* (repairs the Office installation. May sometimes be necessary if you switch between different Access versions and after Windows Updates.)

Comment: I think it is a problem with my JET database engine, how can I fix this?

Comment: See: [How to obtain the latest service pack for the Microsoft Jet 4.0 Database Engine](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114)