# MS Access 2007 Open Separate Form to Specific Record Using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have two forms, one which is a data entry form, the other is a summary form which lists all the records in the database. On the summary form there is a listbox which lists all the records.  I want the user to be able to select a record from the listbox and using a command button, open the second form to the specific record.  I've gotten this work with using a specific field, in one case "Name", using the code below:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEditAddPerson", acNormal, ,"[PersonName]='" & Me.listPeople.Value & "'"
```

but when I realized two people could have the same name, I decided it made sense to use the PersonID which is the primary key and its datatype is "AutoNumber".  I can't seem to get this to work:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEditAddPerson", acNormal, "[PersonName] = " & SelectPersonID
```

Note, I am getting SelectedPersonID by pulling it from ListBox from a hidden column.  I confirmed that I am infact getting correct the number value for the AutoNumber field by displaying it in a MessageBox while trying to debug.

For the WHERE argument of this method/command, I know you are supposed to contain String values in quotes, Integers without, and dates with "#" like in a SQL statement.  I've tried delcaring SelectedPersonID as a string and as an integer and I still cannot get the above to work.  I've even tried the below just to be sure:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEditAddPerson", acNormal, "[PersonName] = " & CInt(SelectPersonID)
```

Each time I get "Type mismatch". Is the AutoNumber field special in the sense that it cannot be used for something like this or does it need to be handled in a special way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `PersonID` is the autonumber primary key, reference it in the fourth `OpenForm` argument (*WhereCondition*).  Your `OpenForm` examples still include `PersonName` instead of `PersonID`.

Also, in your last two examples, PersonID was referenced in the third `OpenForm` argument (*FilterName*).

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEditAddPerson", acNormal, , "[PersonID] = " & SelectPersonID
```

It can be easier to keep track of which option is which by including the option names.

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmEditAddPerson", View:=acNormal, _
    WhereCondition:="[PersonID] = " & SelectPersonID
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your last suggestion helped me clean up my code a bunch and now I am not getting an error BUT when it launches the form, its launches it to a blank/new record not the one that was selected.

Comment: With that form open in Design View, check the Data tab on its property sheet.  Find the Data Entry property.  If it is Yes, change it to No.

Comment: OK, looks like that was the final piece. Data Entry = Yes means the form will allow only addition of new records.  It will not display existing records.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much - I've waste quite a bit of time of this one issue!

Comment: Could you think of a reason of why the DataEntry property of my form would change on its own?  I notice that every once in a while during testing, it gets changed back to = "Yes" and when I click my button described above, it reverts back to a new record.  I do have a new record button as well which just launches the same form in order to add a new record - but I am not setting the DataEntry property of the form explicitly.

Comment: Sorry I've never seen that happen and have no idea how it could change on its own.  Since that seems bizarre to me, I would suspect corruption and perform a decompile.  I'm not confident it's the solution here, but if you want to try you can find instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3266542/77335