# Why does my Access database keep crashing?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was happily creating an Access Database in MS Access 2007 and I recently created a simple logon and splash screen form. Now, everytime i try to enter a string into my textbox, the program keeps crashing.

Error message says: Microsoft Access has stopped working. Windows can try and recover your data.

Remedial Actions Taken:

1. I tried the 'Compact & Repair Database' option. (no good)
2. I tried to delete the logon and splash screens (crashes)
3. I trield Alt+F11 to access the VB code (crashes again)

Below is the simple VB code i inserted at the start:

```
Option Compare Database

Public intlogonattempts As Integer

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
'Check to see if data is entered into the password box
If IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Or Me.txtPassword = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

 'Check value of password in tblEmployees to see if this
    'matches value chosen in combo box

    If Me.txtPassword.Value = "password" Then

        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogon", acSaveNo
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSplash_Screen"

    Else
      MsgBox "Password Invalid. Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, _
            "Invalid Entry!"
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    End If

    'If User Enters incorrect password 3 times database will shutdown

    intlogonattempts = intlogonattempts + 1
    If intlogonattempts > 3 Then
      MsgBox "You do not have access to this database.Please contact admin.", _
               vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there anything underlying here that is affecting/corrupting the program?

thanks

Comment: this sounds like an access-vba question not VB.NET

Comment: @Plutonix definitively DoCmd is Access VBA

Comment: You could try to [decompile/recompile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application)

Comment: I don't know your level of expertise, but I see absolutely no error trapping going on in this code.  This is a horrible strategy and leads to you wondering why you're receiving errors and wondering what they mean.  Proper error trapping should help you narrow this down.

Comment: have you got any events being triggered from the textbox? sounds like you're hitting an infinite loop. You could try pressing Ctrl + Break to force break the code and see where it is crashing.

Comment: Access has always been plagued by issues like this, and they almost always involve references. The first thing I would do is to create a new DB, and import all of my objects from the DB that is having issues. Then, hit Ctrl-G, and look at the Tools > References collection. Try to minimize the references being used. Often during development, Access tried to help by referencing libraries you may not need. One small note, I would exit the SUB in your code where you open the Splash screen as there is no need for the code to continue.

Comment: Thanks! The decompile solved the problem. Many thanks.