# Can’t Open Reports in a Microsoft Access Database

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have a problem. I want to open a report in my microsoft access file in design form, but MS Access doesnt open this report. I dont get any error message, and without freezing.

I have no problem with other report files, but for a special report I have this problem. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, your question is very unclear. Could you please try editing it again? You say design form, then report. What is is?

Comment: simple: I cant open a report without any error or freezing

Comment: So add the error with its appropriate error number and description.

Comment: I am getting no error. I cant open the report without any error message or freezing

Comment: Can you export the report do a different MDB file? what happens? (probably nothing!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as you probably don't want to hear this, I have encountered this a number of times and the best solution was to create a new database and copy each item into it one-by-one.  Sometimes a database carries enough corruption so that even a compact/repair doesn't remove it.

As a "first line of defense" you can try using the undocumented [Decompile switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application), but it's my experience that it rarely works.  Still, it's worth a shot since it's quick and simple.