# Lost Database in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, file-recovery

While "**finishing off**" my database, I chose options from the file menu.

> File Menu -> options -> Current database -> Application Options -> Display Form:  **field**.

Upon hitting OK, Access immediately shut down and now just gives me the "Access has stopped working" message when trying to open the database.

Can I get my database back?  How?

Comment: Not sure this is on-topic as a programming question.

Comment: Have you tried holding the [Shift] key down while opening the database (to bypass the startup form)?

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be, as Gord Thompson has suggested, try and hold the `SHIFT` key to bypass the startup form.

However this scenario suggests that the code might be corrupted. Sometimes, when you copy a file to a new location, the content of the file is disabled. So this could make the file in an openable state, where you would be able to `Compact and Repair`.

If this did not work (copying the file to a new location), then the other option is to **Decompile** your file. So in the file location of copy you just made; create a shortcut. With the following as the `Location of the item`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\PathToYourFile\YourFileName.accdb" /decompile

'Make sure the first path is the path where MSACCESS is installed. 
'I have it in Program Files (x86).......
```

Then double click the Shortcut, you should (hopefully) have your file back up and running.

Comment: Good ideas. More details on increasing the chances of doing an effective decompile can be found in another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/2144390).