# Why did conditional formatting stop working?

Tags: ms-access

I have an access application with a continous form that makes use of the conditional formatting feature for textboxes.

All of a sudden now, the conditional formatting stopped working. I removed the existing formatting and re-applied new ones, yet without success.

When I open an older copy of the application, the formatting still works and looks the same as in the newest copy of the application.

Is there something that I am missing that would determine if conditional formatting is applied on a form or not?

Comment: Have you [decompiled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/77335) since the problem appeared?

Comment: I've tried to, but I am not sure if I followed the instructions correctly.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your db?

Comment: Specify for us the formatting rule. Are your using Field Value Is, Expression Is, looking at Current Record or other Records, Transparent Cell color or Font color?