# Why isn't MS Access "item found in collection?"

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a non-linked table "tblGrantRptData" in which I am trying to modify field records for subsequent filtering and export to EXCEL. I have ensured that all field names are correctly spelled, yet I still get an Error 3265, Item not found in this collection.

I have confirmed that MemmonthlyIncome is the correct spelling and is identified in the design as "currency."

[image]

here is the design veiw that appears to show the field name:

[image]

It stops at this line:
If IsNull (!MemmonthlyIncome) Then

with the error 3265

If I can get some help to resolve this, I would then like to store the range "0-30"....

One suggestion below was to “decompile" and "recompile.”   I have read that this may cause problems when the database is used on multiple workstations.  I have revised the code to just get to first base….Any suggestions?

```vb
Private Sub cmdGenerateGrantRpt_Click()


'now run the qqAll query - this generates the tblGrantRptData - then close the query

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qqAll", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "qqAll"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

'First set up the table: tblGrantRptData with the correct data in fields
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblGrantRptData", dbOpenTable)

'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows and fill in particular values

With rs
If .EOF And .BOF Then
MsgBox "There are no records in this time interval"
Exit Sub

Else
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF = True
        'Replace the monthly income with income categories
        If IsNull(!MemmonthlyIncome) Then
        .Edit
        !MemmonthlyIncome = "0-30"
        .Update
        End If
    Loop
End If
End With
rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up

End Sub
```

Comment: Compact & Repair. Can you edit this field directly in the underlying table using the UI? If so, Search & Replace `MemmonthlyIncome` with the name of the field in Table Design View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get error #3265, *"Item not found in this collection"*, at `IsNull(!MemmonthlyIncome)` in this context ...

```vb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblGrantRptData", dbOpenTable)
With rs
    If IsNull(!MemmonthlyIncome) Then
```

That would happen if *tblGrantRptData* does not include a field named *MemmonthlyIncome*.  What you are seeing as the column heading in the table Datasheet View may be the field's `Caption` property.  You could check the field's `Name` and `Caption` properties in the table's Design View.  Or you could list the actual field names for your table in the Immediate window.

Here's an abbreviated list of the field names in my *Contacts* table:

```vb
set db = currentdb
for each fld in db.TableDefs("Contacts").Fields : ? fld.name : next
ID
Company
Last Name
First Name
```

You just added this screen capture of your table in Design View ...

[image]

Notice the field is named *MemmothlyIncome*, not *MemmonthlyIncome* (*moth* vs. *month*).  So it wasn't a `Name` vs. `Caption` difference after all; you simply tried to use a misspelled field name.  That spelling problem is also visible in the DataSheet View screen capture, but we didn't notice it there.

Comment: I added a screen shot of the "design view"...Also confirmed with the "database documenter" that the field is there....

Comment: The field is named `MemmothlyIncome`, but you're asking for `rs!MemmonthlyIncome` ... those names are not the same ... the first includes 1 `n`, the second includes 2 `n` ... `moth` <> `month`

Comment: You solved this issue...duuu...how many hours have I looked at those names and saw them the same...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, there is no `Is Null` expression as there is in SQL. Change to `IsNull(rs!MemmonthlyIncome)`.

Possibly, Null is being referenced in recordset collection and hence returning the error.

Comment: good catch.  However, still stops at this line:     If rs!MemmonthlyIncome * 12 <= 30000 Or IsNull(rs!MemmonthlyIncome) Then      with error:3265 @Parfait

Comment: Come to think of it too, `Is Null` would have outputted a different error. However, I just recreated your table and all worked. Check the field name carefully (three m's). Else, try [decompiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application) the code or check for lingering [breakpoints](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/vbadebug/debug02.php).