# Edits getting lost

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, multi-user

**Background:**

Split access database, maximum two users. The back end is located on one of the two computers on a mapped drive and the front end is local. The computers are connected to the router by wifi. (I am trying unsuccessfully to get them to connect the computers via cable)

**Edit:** This problem is now happening in a single user environment.

**Problem:**

This is happening on one specific form only. Its underlying table has a multi-value field.

**Issue 1:** We have a situation where a field will be edited, but as soon as the focus moves to another field the edit reverts back to its original value.

**Issue 2:** When editing one field, some of the other fields are getting the values of the previously shown record.

Note: Navigation from one record to the other is done as follows:

```
    Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "ID = " & cmbLocateRecipientID
    Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
```

The issues only happen occassionaly.

This is an extremely weird behaviour on the part of Access, so when the users first reported the issues I was convinced that they were entering information mistakenly into another record. However, they have since shown me the issue happening live.

Closing and reopening the form solves the issue. However, they can obviously not work in such a fashion.

I cannot reproduce the problem on my development machine.

Comment: I would try to find out if wifi connections are the source of the problem.  Set up a test user to connect via remote desktop to the machine which hosts the shared backend db.  If the lost edit problem disappears in that context, you can use that fact as supporting evidence for your recommendation that they provide wired connections for reliable Access performance.  Or they could use Terminal Server or Citrix to give all the wifi users remote session capability.

Comment: One of the users is working on the 'server' and they are having this issue too. Unless, the data is being transferred via the router because the drive is mapped? I don't think that makes sense!

Comment: Me neither.  But you could absolutely rule out network work access for that user by changing that one user's front end linked table `Connect` properties to use the local drive instead of network share.  However, based on your comment, I suspect my hunch was just wrong.  Good luck.

Comment: Is that the only form using the `RecordSetClone`/`Bookmark` style navigation?

Comment: Other forms also use it.

Comment: Wow, almost 2 years. I assume you tried the usual: 1) Compact&Repair on FE+BE 2) [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271) on the Frontend, 3) Try to reproduce it with the users backend database on your system ?

Comment: When all this is done, my suggestion would be to get rid of the multi-value field, and replace it with a regular table and a one-to-many relation.

Comment: I stripped out the multi value fields as you suggested, alas the problem persists.

Comment: are you using a continuous form ? if not, can you change your navigation method to direct SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

*Me would think* you have to specify and use the recordset object:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "ID = " & Me!cmbLocateRecipientID.Value & ""
If Not rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If

Set rs = Nothing
```

A similar change may be needed in other parts of your code.

Comment: Note that he navigation currently works, so I don't see why the change you made should make a difference regarding the issue of data loss. Please explain if I have not understood the intention.

Comment: First, you are opening RecordsetClone twice. Not needed. Second, you have to try _something_ to proceed. Third, this is all we have; the issue could more likely be caused by code run when updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use MS Access on a wireless network as "wireless" does not keep a continuous link between the frontend and backend. There are occasional dropouts which you don't notice with most things, however MS Access is very sensitive to this and you will have all sorts of problems over wireless. You must use a physical cable as the connection.