# VBA code stopped working as intended

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have weird issue, code that was working suddenly started to generate an issue (i have no clue how to bypass it)

I have List Box (List2) on Form1, It's populated by:

```
SELECT [queryFormyTradycyjne].[Nr Maszyny], [queryFormyTradycyjne].[UID], [queryFormyTradycyjne].[Nazwa], [queryFormyTradycyjne].[UAP], [queryFormyTradycyjne].[Linia], [queryFormyTradycyjne].[GAP], [queryFormyTradycyjne].[Status] FROM queryFormyTradycyjne ORDER BY [Nr Maszyny];
```

queryFormyTradycyjne code:

```
SELECT Lista.[Nr Maszyny], Lista.[Nazwa], Lista.[UAP], Lista.[Linia], Lista.[GAP], Lista.[Status], Lista.[UID]
FROM Lista
WHERE Lista.isValid=False And Lista.UID Like 'FF*';
```

and if I'll double click on an item from List2 it supose to deliver value to the other form (AwariaZgloszenieNew), to the text field named *txtNrMaszyny*.

THAT was working just fine, since 2 hours ago. I actually didnt touch a thing in the code nor in any of these forms. I checked that on several PC's with different Access version installed.
Same result: Error **Method 'Item' of object 'Forms' failed** (-2146500594 (800f000e))

My VBA code for double click event:

```
Public strSelectedItem As String

Private Sub List2_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Dim varItem As Variant

With Me.List2
    For Each varItem In .ItemsSelected
    strSelectedItem = .ItemData(varItem)
    Next
End With

DoCmd.OpenForm "AwariaZgloszenieNew"

[Forms]![AwariaZgloszenieNew].[txtNrMaszyny] = strSelectedItem

End Sub
```

Anyone with any kind of idea?

Comment: Have you tried a compact and repair on the DB?

Comment: Im not quite sure how to do that. Edit: if u r talking about that button "Compact and repair" - after clicking it nothing changed...

Comment: On database tools tab of the ribbon menu there is a "Compact and repair Database" button.  Back up your database first.

Comment: Suddenly my front end to the database it ~3mb, comparing to the backup of it i have - 40~mb. What just happened? :| Backup is kinda old..

Comment: That's normal, it's the "Compact" part of "Compact and repair".

Comment: The compact takes out old data. When you delete records they are not actually taken out of the database. So those are removed.  And when you do a query, I believe it actually creates a table "behind the scenes" that is left behind until compacted. https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2  and here is some more info. http://www.databasedev.co.uk/compacting-and-repairing-ms-access.html

Comment: its not about the compact to be fair, im looking into vba code in my other forms - ots gone (even with a copy before compacting)
I dont get it - why? only i have access to vba code (password protected and well, in corp noone take care about it)

Answer (score 1):

If "Compact and repair" doesn't help, there are two more things you can try.

- Decompile

[How does one decompile and recompile a database application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application)
Follow the steps in David-W-Fenton's answer to the letter.

- Create a new database and import all objects from the old one.

Edit -- just saw your latest comment.
If the VBA code is gone, and no working backup available, some parts may be lost. For the future: during development, "Compact and repair" and (to a lesser extent) Decompile should be regular tasks.

I don't know how Decompile works with password protected code.
IMHO a better option to protect code in Access is by distributing .mde frontends instead of .mdb