# Why do my Microsoft DLLs keep getting un-referenced in MS Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, dll, vba

I have a very complicated MS Access 2010 Database. When I lock it down and publish for users, it works fine. But whenever I open the database for development it un-references these three Microsoft DLLs. Surely this isn't normal behavior. Has anyone seen this behavior and know how to prevent Access from un-referencing these DLLs?

Note: there references in question are the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th unchecked references. This is what they look like every time i open my database for development. They are still sorted at the top, but they are unchecked somehow.

[image: References Screen Shot]

Comment: Are both you and your users using access 2010?

Comment: Yes, the entire company has either the full version of access 2010 or the access run-time engine. I've tested the published version with both the full version and just the engine and that doesn't seem to make a difference (of course you can't open the database in development in the engine, so i did not test that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the things I would try:

1. That lonely "Database" reference in there is odd. Can you try to get rid of it by deregistering whatever it points to? Or at least move it down.
2. [Decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271) your database (follow these steps to the letter!)
3. Create a new database and import all objects from the old one.

Comment: I'll mark you as the correct answer. I figured #3 would solve my problem, but I was hoping someone would just "know" what exactly the problem was. Turns out it probably had something to do with that rogue "Database" reference. I couldn't figure out how to get rid of it. It was a reference to itself (!?). anyway. #3 worked. Thanks.