# Access compiles all code before running first function

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The application consists of 3 parts: frontend, backend and common library, used in both parts. The application has autoreconnect feature, which offers to select common library if reference to the library is broken and then it reconnects all tables. Application checks for valid common library reference in very first Init function, called from autoexec macro, the function doesn't have any references to common library. Everything worked fine for a long time, but now the application gives "Syntax Error" at start if the common library not found. I have no idea what happened with this application, I have many other applications with the same technology, they work fine on the same PC.

I tried to compact/repair, decompile, compact/repair and compile again as it was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application) - no luck. VBA editor and database options have the same settings for broken and working databases.
Any ideas what can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for question, I had to dig in more deeply before asking, I found the problem and, probably, it will be interesting for someone.

I ran thru backups and found the copy where application works fine. Application has stopped to work when in the module with Init function was declared function with Enum type declared in common library. When I changed data type to Integer instead of Enum, application worked fine.

Summary: Access checks data types of all functions, declared in module before running particular function and stops to work if **any** function data type not declared in current application.