# Left Function Returns 'Type Mismatch'

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database containing several tables which have fields to record phone numbers. Their data type is Short Text, allow zero length - No. I have set up Input Masks as follows:

```
If Left(Phone, 3) = "011" Or Left(Phone, 3) = "030" Then
    Me.Phone.InputMask = "0000 000 0000;;' '"
ElseIf Left(Phone, 3) = "020" Or Left(Phone, 4) = "0121" Then
    Me.Phone.InputMask = "000 0000 0000;;' '"
ElseIf Left(Phone, 4) = "0191" Then
    Me.Phone.InputMask = "000 000 0000;;' '"
Else
    Me.Phone.InputMask = "00000 000000;;' '"
End If
```

On all tables except one this works fine. But, for one table I get an error message 'Run-time error 13 Type Mismatch'. What is even more strange is that the input mask works fine if placed in an unbound control on the same form, e.g. data = 'Left(Phone,3)'.

Comment: The control "Phone" on the form is derived directly from the field "Phone" on the underlying table which is Short Text.

Comment: Short Text, Field Size 30.

Comment: Yes. Plain Text; Enabled Yes; Locked No.

Comment: I don't think so, as I would be in breach of UK law (Data Protection Act). However, it helps to know that you can't imagine how the problem might arise. It's very intriguing to me.

Comment: I don't allow zero-length strings. I'll set up some non confidential data and get back. Thank you for your comments - pity I can't give credit for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a string variable for the `Left` function?

```vb
Dim strPhone As String
strPhone = Nz(Me!Phone, "")

If Left(strPhone, 3) = "011" Or Left(strPhone, 3) = "030" Then
    Me!Phone.InputMask = "0000 000 0000;;' '"
ElseIf Left(strPhone, 3) = ' etc.
```

---

**Solution:**

It turned out there was a text field called `Left` on the form, which caused this odd error.

If renaming the field is impractical, you can avoid the error by using the qualifier `VBA`:

```vb
If VBA.Left(strPhone, 3) = "011" Then
```

but not using [reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) for field names is better. :)

Comment: @GreatCrosby: In which line exactly do you get the error?

Comment: I have a form which displays data about certain people. The On Current event triggers a sub routine which contains the Left function. On opening, form gives Run-time error '13' - Type Mismatch.

Comment: @GreatCrosby: If you use the code in my answer, and start the sub with `On Error Goto 0` if you have error handling in place. Then which line is highlighted by the Debugger when the error message is shown? --- [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: It's the first line that has 'Left(strPhone etc). Same result if I do it my old way - Left(Phone...).

Comment: @GreatCrosby: Then either your database is broken (do Compact&Repair and [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application/3268188#3268188), check the VBA editor for broken references), or you have something else called `Left` in your module, a function or an array perhaps.

Comment: That's the answer! I have a field called 'Left', meaning the date that a person left the organisation. I just need to change its name. I think you deserve quite a few points for this.

Comment: @GreatCrosby: feel free to accept and upvote the answer :o) --- I just reproduced the behavior, and must say I find it very odd of Access to show this problem as a runtime error.

Comment: I can see your solution but it doesn't seem to allow me to accept it.

Comment: @GreatCrosby: It is one answer, I added the solution to it (using the string variable and still getting the runtime error ruled out everything else).

Comment: Sorry, I meant I can't see how I rate your answer as 'accepted' for StackOverflow purposes.

Comment: @GreatCrosby: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

`[Phone]` can be *Null*, so apply `Nz`:

```
If Left(Nz(Phone), 3) = "011" Or Left(Nz(Phone), 3) = "030" Then
' etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't help. Also, my other tables have nulls in the phone field but those table work fine.

Comment: Oh, so it is the InputMask that fails. It seems OK to me. But try with a different setting.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand 'different setting'. However, thinking about the whole problem, I said earlier that I don't get the problem with an unbound control on the form. So I'm wondering if the problem is somehow with the phone field, even though it says it is text. Only thing I can think of now is to  rebuild the whole table from scratch.

Comment: It should work with text, indeed if it does for your other forms. A different setting - just for testing - could be: `"00 00 00 00"`

Comment: Thanks. Did that, but omitted the If statement, leaving just the Me.Phone.InputMask = "00000 000000;;' '". This did nothing - no error message and phone numbers left untouched by the input mask. So  the left function doesn't work because of type mismatch and the input mask doesn't work for some weird reason?

Comment: You may need a bang: `Me!Phone.InputMask`