# MS-Access 2007 Form cannot edit data until Form changed to Design View & back to Form View

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

**Update:  Manually losing the form and re-opening it also causes editing to be allowed, please see Step 4 below and "Additional Notes" section below.  Thanks!**

An MS-Access 2007 database that I have simplified a great deal during troubleshooting still has the same problem:

1. Restart Access and open the database
2. The autoexec calls a vba function that initializes some TempVars, then opens a form with: `DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="MainEditor"
3. All Bound and Un-Bound Text Boxes and Combo Boxes display their data
   correctly, but **NONE of them can be edited.**  Keystrokes are ignored, pull-downs on Combo Boxes display lists of choices correctly but no choice can be selected.
4. Change the form's view to Design View, then immediately change it back to Form View. Alternatively, manually close the Form and then re-open it.
5. All the controls continue to display their data correctly, but **now ALL of
   them can be edited normally.**

After changing to Design View and back to Form View, the Form is editable normally until Access is shut down and restarted.

**Additional Notes:**
I tried adding a `DoCmd.Close` and a `DoCmd.FormOpen` immediately after the original `DoCmd.FormOpen` in the startup function called by the Autoexec macro, but the Form remained unable to accept edits.  Manually closing the form, and then manually re-opening it, seems to work every time.  Is there any chance that Access needs a delay to process before opening the form, and manually doing the close/open cycle provides that time window?

Here's some background:

- The Table has a primary index, 4 other indexes, and one-to-many relations to 7 other tables.
- The Form's Record Source is the Table, and Allow Edits = Yes.
- All the controls on the Form are set: Enabled = Yes, and Locked = No.
- There are no sub-forms, only the one Form.

This isn't much to go on.  If you ask for further specifics I'd be glad to provide them.

Thank you.  Dave

Comment: Does decompile eliminate the problem?  [How does one decompile and recompile a database application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application)

Comment: Have you tried leaving off the DataMode setting and going with the default.  I don't use it on my form opening.

Comment: @HansUp Thanks for the good advice and the URL.  I followed the decompile / compile procedure, but sadly it seems to have had no effect in terms of my problem.  Thank you though, I did not know about decompiling.

Comment: @akc42 I've tried leaving out DataMode again just to make sure.  I only added the explicit argument to allow editing in frustration to try and insist that the form open and allow edits.  You are correct that "acFormEdit" is the default, and I should not need to include it in the actual arguments list.  Thank you for the good suggestion!

Comment: Just a long shot, but based on a similar Excel bug: try minimizing and the maximizing the Access window after start. Or try switching to another form or any element inside the database, then going back to your form.

Comment: @vacip, Thank you for your suggestions!  Although the specific actions you suggested weren't successful, based on your ideas I tried manually closing the Form and immediately manually opening the Form.  This was successful, but unfortunately simply programming a DoCmd.Close followed by a 2nd DoCmd.OpenForm was not successful.  I have updated my original question with these results.  Thank you very much for the excellent ideas!

Comment: Instead of using an autoexec macro, specify a startup form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an Autoexec macro, specify a startup form.

Comment: Nailed it. Isolating the form from the startup code started me down the path of checking everything that ran at startup, whether connected with this form or starting the system. Tedious because much of the code is needed to get the system running...otherwise it wouldn't be there. Anyway, many stubs later I found a typo in the name of a TempVar and that was the beginning of a sequence that turned off (among other things) the editing functionality. In other words, it's my fault. :-) **Thank you everyone for all the help;** I was really stuck. Dave