# Microsoft crash upon reaching "End Sub" in VBA for MSAccess

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having a problem with a form that adds a source association to a company record. In the main form, the user specifies the source name to be associated, and then this form opens to allow the user to confirm the name, and pick a year, if that name has more than 1 year associated with it. When the user clicks on "Continue", the code checks if the association already exists, whether the source has multiple years, and if so, if the user has selected which year to put with the associated name. When there are not multiple records (ie the name has only one year,) the continue button works just fine, but when the user has to pick a value of the year, the continue buttons works fine and does its job, entering the new association into the database, until it gets to the Exit sub line under the Exit_cmdAssign_Click line, and then the whole Access stops. I get a message box saying "Microsoft has stopped working", it backs up the database and eventually reopens it. At one point, as it stopped it gave me an option to debug in Visual Studio, but there, there were problems finding necessary files for the debug. Before I tried to debug, it said, "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in DWWIN.EXE [8940]."
Does anyone know how an exit sub can cause such a crash when one extra variable is included in an equation, which actually performs as it should, but then seems to cause problems exiting the sub?

Comment: did my answer help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Crashes of Access are not regular errors that you can fix by changing your VBA code. No matter what your code is, under no circumstances should this happen.

That said, from time to time Access *does* crash. Most of the time the cause lies in an inconsistent compilation state. That can be easily remedied by decompiling the database. Follow the instructions over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3266849/6216216

And make sure you have a backup copy of the database before you decompile.