# Issue with MS-Access Application on shared network(Citrix) using by many users simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2003, citrix

A MS-access application with SQL Server backend running on a shared location(Citrix) through a MDE file. It is running fine on local machine but when multiple users generate the certificate simultaneously, it gives the error and may that file get corrupt as well because after getting the error that file does not work even on local environment.

[MS-ACCESS Application ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V4ir.png)

Comment: Each user should have their own front-end.

Comment: Gustav has written about Access deployment on Citrix here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37293784/3820271