# VBA modules have been saved with errors

Tags: vba, ms-access, data-recovery

I have a database with tables that are linked to a different database in a network drive. (The other database is on a different machine, and a network drive on my machine is mapped to it.)

While I was running some VBA code the connection to the network drive was broken, and I got an error message.
When I tried accessing any **local** tables in my database, or when I tried closing Access I got error messages. 
I closed access through the task manager, and now when I open it I get the following message:

> The VBA modules in this database appear to have been saved with errors. Access can recover the modules, but you should backup the database first...

I backed up and then clicked OK, but the modules have been entirely wiped out.
In the backup I cannot access the modules, I just get that message again.

Please help! Sadly I do not have a backup from before, and I need the modules. Is there a way to recover at least the modules? Even in text file?

I tried importing the modules into a different database, but I get the same error message.

EDIT: When I try to recover I get the following message:

> Cannot open database ''. It may not be a database your application recognizes, or your file may be corrupt.

What does this mean? It seems like Access is trying to access an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh... That one hurts! I've been in a similar situation but not exactly the same way. The good news is that you can almost always recover from these situations. Try this: Create a new blank database and import all tables, queries, forms, reports, macros, and modules into the new database...

If that's not possible you may have to decompile the database. See: https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/errors/Bad_DLL_Calling_Convention.asp

Comment: I'm somewhat less optimistic for the import, but it's worth a try. For a full decompile run, see: [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271) @MJH

Comment: I tried your link for decompiling, but I typed this: **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\msaccess.exe/decompile** in ommand prompt, and I got
**'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: I tried decompile but I get the same error as the first error in my question.

Comment: Does the db normally open to a Form as default? If so try holding the Shift key down with the decompile.

Comment: @MJH: Re. "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file": That's probably because you didn't enclose the entire File Path in double quotes (").  In Window Command Prompt, any Folder Path or File Path that contains a space(s) has to be enclosed in double quotes.  Also, I believe you need to have at least one space between "msaccess.exe" and "/decompile" (i.e. between a command and its parameter(s), if any).

Answer (score 1):

Do double-check the path. Most likely it is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE"
```

and a space is missing:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" /decompile
```

That's for A2016. It is *Office15* for A2013.