# VBA invalid .(dot) or ! or parenthesis after splitting database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database with a form that was working just fine, however now after I split the Database I'm getting an error:

**There is an invalid use of the . (dot) or ! operator or invalid Parentheses.**

This is the code targeted by the Debugger

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("Insert Into TestingStatistics (BadgeNumber, TestName, College, Instructor, SigninTime, Special) " & _
"Values ('" & Me.txtBadgeNo.Value & "', '" & strTestName & "', '" & strCollege & "', '" & strInstructor & "', Now(), '" & Me.chkSpecial.Value & "');")
```

When I remove the `Me.txtBadgeNo.Value` and `Me.chkSpecial.Value`

```
"Values (" & strTestName & "', '" & strCollege & "', '" & strInstructor & "', Now());")
```

I get the error:

**Syntax Error (Missing operator) in query expression 'Medicine', 'Medicine, 'Larsen', Now());'.**

Again, this worked before I split the database, I need this insert statement to work, what's going on?

Comment: Replace `DoCmd.RunSQL` with `Debug.Print` and update your question with the exact SQL that is failing.

Comment: `Debug.Print` isn't showing anything besides the first error

Comment: Adding the quotes didn't change the error, though it's a fair point.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: I followed How To link.  it's now giving me the same error on the strSQL **There is an invalid use of the . (dot) or ! operator or invalid Parentheses.**

Comment: This is a head scratcher, there doesn't seem to be anything directly wrong from what I can see, and if you're looking for the specific SQL error you don't see anything glaringly wrong either.

Comment: No, the most complicated value is Now() which is Date/Time.

Comment: `TestingStatistics` is a table

Comment: I mean I'm totally willing to show that to you.  I don't have the ability to give you more than Access is giving me.  I've followed the directions, if you have better or more suggestions I'm willing.

Comment: Check out this [Access Programmers thread](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=130986) which solved the OP's problem with your exact error. You may have an [Access References Problem](http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/AccessReferenceErrors.html) and need to refresh.

Comment: Parfait's suggestions sounds good. If it doesn't help, you can narrow the problem down by adding lines `Debug.Print Me.txtBadgeNo.Value` etc. Also try `Debug.Print Me!txtBadgeNo.Value`.

Comment: [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271) may help also.

Comment: I'm an idiot and have been fighting myself.  Close this thread with a dunce cap, I started investigating references, I was opening a form directly while the variables were referencing an unopen form.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just delete values; the count must match the count of fields.

Try this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("Insert Into TestingStatistics (BadgeNumber, TestName, College, Instructor, SigninTime, Special) " & _
"Values (" & Me!txtBadgeNo.Value & ", '" & strTestName & "', '" & strCollege & "', '" & strInstructor & "', Now(), " & Me!chkSpecial.Value & ");")
```

Edit, to debug:

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = _
    "Insert Into TestingStatistics (BadgeNumber, TestName, College, Instructor, SigninTime, Special) " & _
    "Values (" & Me!txtBadgeNo.Value & ", '" & strTestName & "', '" & strCollege & "', '" & strInstructor & "', Now(), " & Me!chkSpecial.Value & ");"

Debug.Print SQL

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: Right, obviously sorry.  Yeah the Me! isn't helping still getting the first error.

Comment: OK. Then try to output the assembled SQL and tell us what you see. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

"Values (" & strTestName & "', '" & strCollege & "', '" & strInstructor & "', '" & Now() & "');")