# Runtime error in Access 2010 when importing csv with VBA

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

i am writing a simple application in Access 2010 which imports FlatFiles into the database according to an import specification (fixed column lengths).

The following line:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "Betreuer_Importspezifikation", "Betreuer", Me.txt_betreuer_path, 0
```

Produces this error:

> Runtime Error '3035': System resouce exceeded

When importing this exact File with this specification in the table manually everything works fine. The same line works with other files and the according specifications. And i also tried to not use the textfield but hardcode the path (same error occured).

Also the file that raises this error only has 37 records with 11 columns and files with >4k records and 150 columns work find so i don't think the size is the problem (although the error message sounds like it).

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? I am really out of ideas at this point.

BR

Comment: If it's just the one file, I suspect that it's broken in some way - i.e. missing an end of file marker or something like that.

Comment: I tried creating a completelly new file and manually added a few records with the column lengths as in the specifications and i got the same error. And like i said when importing the file manually it works perfectly

Comment: Have you done Repair+Compact and [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271) on your DB?

Comment: Just tried it and didn't help either but thanks