# How to increase VBA error output to diagnose consistent crashing after "File not found" error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is there a way I can make the application MS Access and VBA more verbose in order to better diagnose errors from the IDE?

I open my MS Access project, I get a message dialog box, titled "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" with the message "File not found:" without any path specified.   Opening the form file works as expected.

When I go into VBA, I can run some commands from the Immediate window.  The following actions will make MS Access crash, showing a messaged box titled "Microsoft Access has stopped working":

- Closing the database
- Stopping the debugger (it opens being active, trying to load a form)
- Selecting text of the procedure I was working on when MS-Access / VBA initially crashed.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question, but it seems the underlying problem has been fixed by deleting the procedure in question, letting MS Access crash and re-opening VBA.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the question in your title:** If the error is actually cause by VBA code, you can catch the error (using `On Error Goto ...`) and provide additional information based on the context of your method (the file you were trying to open, etc.). Unfortunately, there is no magical switch to make the built-in error messages more useful.

**To answer the question in your question body:** From what you describe, the error is *not* caused by actual user-supplied VBA code. Instead, your database or its VBA module is corrupt (Access crashing or showing seemingly random errors is a strong sign of that). Repair, compact and [decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3266542/87698) your database. It might be worth checking out the VBA references as well, so see if any of those are missing.

Answer (score 0):

can you execute the command resume in the immediate window ? it should send you back to the code line where the file was not found.