# VBA: Access crash with no error when calling function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Issues when calling this

```
Public IE As InternetExplorer
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
Dim el As Object

Public Function IEClick(Idstr As String)
Do
    Set el = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set el = IE.Document.getElementById(Idstr)
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoEvents
    Sleep (100)
Loop While el Is Nothing
Sleep (1000)
IE.Document.getElementById(Idstr).Click
End Function
```

Its to loop true untill it finds the correct elementid. I crash with no error message on this line `IEClick Str(Item)` when the Function is being called like so.

```
For Each Item In coll
    IEClick Str(Item)
    p = p + 1
Next
```

This is the full body of code.

```
Public Sub AutoExtract()
Dim ProgressBar_Extract As Object
Dim coll As Collection
Set coll = New Collection

'/////////////////controls in order///////////////
With coll
    .Add "ctl00_cmdCustom"
    .Add "chkAll"
    .Add "ctl00_cmdContinue"
End With
Me.ProgressBar_Extract.Max = coll.Count
'////////////////////start ie//////////////////
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
With IE
    '.AddressBar = False
    '.MenuBar = False
    .Navigate ("*****")
    .Visible = True
End With
'//////////////////////Start Automation///////////////////
For Each Item In coll
    IEClick Str(Item)
    p = p + 1
Next
MsgBox "Extract Complete"
End Sub
```

I narrowed it down to `IEClick Str(Item)`.When debugging if I put a stop on it and step to next line it crashes.

Comment: What exactly does *"crash with no error message"* mean? It locks up? Or it closes (then does the Access process still run?) ?

Comment: @Andre closes process is not running.

Comment: As a first step I recommend a full [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271).

Comment: If that doesn't help, please put a breakpoint inside the function (on `Set el = Nothing`), and step from there to find the exact line where it crashes.

Comment: I have decomplied. it crashes right after this point `IEClick Str(Item)`. If i write out `IEClick "ctl00_cmdCustom"` it works just fine with no crash. It has to be something to do with `Item`. Is it an issue with maybe the `For` loop thinking of `Item` as an object but im using it as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't use `Item` as variable name, it is a reserved word in VBA (Collection.Item)

2) Put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module.
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

3) I couldn't reproduce a crash, but I get a runtime error when calling `Str()` with a string parameter.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestCrash()

    Dim coll As Collection
    Dim vItem As Variant

    Set coll = New Collection

    With coll
        .Add "ctl00_cmdCustom"
        .Add "chkAll"
        .Add "ctl00_cmdContinue"
    End With

    For Each vItem In coll
        ' Gives Runtime error 13 "Type mismatch"
        ' Debug.Print Str(vItem)

        ' This works
        Debug.Print vItem
    Next

End Sub
```

and if it works, adapt your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help Andre. I will give this a go and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Str() is very buggy and crash my access sometimes better use cstr()