# Access 2010: Error message goes away when I open visual basic

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Currently finishing up making a database and ran into a problem. I have a continuous form with a button to "Update Notice" next to it. It worked fine until I saved and closed the database. Then I suddenly began getting an error that said, **"The expression On Load you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Object or class does not support the set of events"**. I get a similar error message when I close the form.

The field it is affecting is a date field, that is set to inactive if the status of the record is "Open" and active if the record is "Resolved". This is now always active.

The really weird part is that **as soon as I open and close the Visual Basic window, it works**. The error message goes away and the date field behaves as expected.

Any ideas why this would be?

I can always go back to a prior version of the database and work from there, but I'd like to avoid regressing in my project!

Comment: Sounds like a good reason to decompile and recompile your database. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application/3266849#3266849 for a guide on how to do that.

Comment: Open VBE >> Debug >> Compile Database. That should fix the issue.