# Stumped as to why Access is asking me to enter a parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a combo box called "manufacturer" that will update the combo box called "productName" but when I select the manufacturer, I get a prompt asking for the parameter. The SQL statement for the ProductName query is below.

```
SELECT ProductsTable.ProductID, ProductsTable.ProductName, 
ProductsTable.ManufacturerID 
FROM ProductsTable 
WHERE (((ProductsTable.ManufacturerID)=[Forms]![NewComplaint]![manufacturer])) 
ORDER BY ProductsTable.ProductName;
```

When the Manufacturer is selected, this is the prompt that is displayed.

[image: Enter Parameter Value (Image)]

Comment: Double-check form name and control name. And if it's on a subform, you'll have to address that too.

Comment: Form and control names are both correct as these have been checked and suggested by the Expression Builder in Access. There is also no subform.

Comment: Hmm. Is there code in the AfterUpdate event of `manufacturer` to requery `productName`? -- Also, a screenshot of design view of the form might give a hint. -- Or as last resort, if you can upload a sample database to a file hoster.

Comment: Do you have a product name in the combo box?  That is not an ID. In the properties of the combobox, look for the bound column value.

Comment: Andre: the code to request is there in the afterUpdate. Everything works when I substitute the value in the prompt but what appears to be happening is it not taking the manufacturerID from the "manufacturer" combo box

Comment: There are some things that can go wrong with multi-column cascading combo boxes. But this prompt is simply Access' way of saying *I can't resolve `[Forms]![NewComplaint]![manufacturer]` - please give me the value*.

Comment: So how would I resolve it? For some bizarre reason, if I make a new database with only 2 combo boxes and different tables the same method works perfectly?

Comment: This is one of those question that usually can only be solved in two ways: either you find the problem yourself, or you upload a sample database to a file hoster where someone can take a look at it.

Comment: I'll upload the database asap. It's one I'm using to experiment with so the content isn't really a big issue as this will be changed later

Comment: I uploaded the database to here: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/699093/A1_DB1.accdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite unexpected: your database is **corrupted** in a way that I haven't seen yet (AFAIR).

After opening the form, I tried a few things in the Immediate Window that usally work without problems, and got various errors:

```
? Forms!NewComplaint.Name
```

> Automation Error

```
? Form_NewComplaint.Name
```

> Not enough memory

Compact & Repair and [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271) didn't help.

**Solution**: Create a new database, import everything from the existing database.

Now the combo boxes work without problems.

See http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html
(and for possible future problems: http://allenbrowne.com/recover.html)

Comment: I will give this a try and get back to you.