# Microsoft Access Hangs when on the End of Function

Tags: vba, ms-access, freeze

As the title says, I am being faced with an issue where my Access applications hangs on the line (see below). THis function is being called from somewhat of a busy form.

```
 End Function
```

I have done quite a bit of research to try and pin point the issue.

I stepped through the code watching the locals window looking for hanging objects.

I have verified that all recordsets are being dealt with appropirately (there happens to be none actually).

I have converted any sql strings in the properties dialog to saved queries (I thought this would help due to the form having quite a few controls).

I have added error handling t the function to see if there were any issues. Peculiarly enough, the error handling does alleviate the issue temporarily. After a short session of banging on the form that calls the function, eventually it'll go back to the hanging. If I open and reclose the DB this also helps. THis tells me that something is bloating/hanging in the back ground, but Im not sure what else I need to check.

Any pointers, advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

function

```
Public Function IsAdmin() As Boolean
On Error GoTo IsAdminErr

Dim errany
IsAdmin = AdminUser ' adminuser is a global variable that is set on file open
Debug.Print ;

 IsAdminCleanUp:

Exit Function

 IsAdminErr:
 If DBEngine.Errors.Count > 1 Then
    'ODBC Error
    For Each errany In DBEngine.Errors
         Debug.Print ; errany.Number
         Debug.Print ; errany.Description
    Next errany
Else  'Access Error    
    Debug.Print ; errany.Number
    Debug.Print ; errany.Description
End If
GoTo IsAdminCleanUp
End Function
```

Comment: If this is not enough information just let me know I can add whatever.

Comment: Uhm, so, what's the function returning? A 42TB variant array?

Comment: Please try to provide enough information for us to replicate the problem (try to replicate it yourself in a second database with the minmal required code). Currently, it's hard for me to help you with this little information.

Comment: @Mat'sMug it returns a boolean value. The original function before I added error handling was just assigning true/false to whether or not end user was "admin"

Comment: Note the things that happen when a function ends 1. a value gets returned 2. any object that's out of scope gets marked for removal (garbage collection). That last one might be the most obvious culprit in a hang, if only a boolean gets returned

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth except VBA isn't garbage-collected, it's ref-counted ;-) ..but yeah, could be something like it.

Comment: @Yowek I posted the current state of the function - the error handling is a recent addition. I guess i wasn't clear that it hangs on exit function now. Sorry if that wasnt clear. THe extra space is more of a formatting issue from my posting here. There are no extra spaces in the editor within access.

Comment: Probably best to update the question so that the problem statement refers to the posted code.  It's a really weird issue, so the answer could be really weird too, and therefore the more exact the question description the better the chance of solving.

Comment: Have you tried decompiling the DB?  It can sometimes fix these oddball issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen a function stall on `End Function`, but your `IsAdminErr` subroutine isn't clearing its error state properly. This:

```
GoTo IsAdminCleanUp
```

Should be:

```
Resume IsAdminCleanUp
```

I don't expect it to fix anything though - the local error state *should* get cleared on exit anyway.

Comment: I doubt it will fix it either but anything is better than nothing at this point. thank dude