# ADO recordset datatype mismatch on MoveNext method

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb, recordset

I have an issue which I seem to be unable to solve after extensive Googling.  Since a week one of my functions written in VBA gives a "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

The line the error occurs is "rstBom.MoveNext".  I seem to lack the knowledge (I'm no schooled vba programmer) to understand how a skip in a recordset can cause a data type mismatch...

```
Public Function Packing_PL_BOM()

Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rstIN As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rstBom As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rstSC As New ADODB.Recordset

CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "delete from tblPacking_private_label_base"

rst.Open "qryPacking_Private_label_stock", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
rstIN.Open "tblPacking_private_label_base", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

If Not rst.EOF Then
    Do Until rst.EOF
        rstBom.Open "select * from ZBOM_XLS where val(Component) = " & rst.Fields("matnr").Value, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
         If Not rstBom.EOF Then
            Do Until rstBom.EOF
                rstIN.AddNew
                rstIN.Fields("matnr").Value = rst.Fields("matnr").Value
                rstIN.Fields("material_description").Value = rst.Fields("material_description").Value
                rstIN.Fields("Value").Value = rst.Fields("Value").Value
                rstIN.Fields("description").Value = rst.Fields("description").Value
                rstIN.Fields("uom").Value = rst.Fields("uom").Value
                rstIN.Fields("Stock_pack_PC").Value = rst.Fields("SumOfUnrestricted").Value
                rstIN.Fields("Packed_matnr").Value = rstBom.Fields("Material").Value
                rstIN.Fields("Packed_description").Value = rstBom.Fields("Material Description").Value

                Select Case rstBom.Fields("Alternative BOM").Value
                    Case "1"
                        rstSC.Open "select * from qryMaterial_Class_SC_Values where matn = " & rstBom.Fields("material").Value & " and [Supply Chain] = 'PRODUCTION'", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                        If Not rstSC.EOF Then
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "X"

                        Else
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "DEL"

                        End If
                        rstSC.Close

                    Case "4"
                        rstSC.Open "select * from qryMaterial_Class_SC_Values where matn = " & rstBom.Fields("material").Value & " and [Supply Chain] = 'PINGUIN'", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                        If Not rstSC.EOF Then
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "X"
                        Else
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "DEL"

                        End If
                        rstSC.Close

                    Case "5"
                        rstSC.Open "select * from qryMaterial_Class_SC_Values where matn = " & rstBom.Fields("material").Value & " and [Supply Chain] = 'SIVAFROST'", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                        If Not rstSC.EOF Then
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "X"

                        Else
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "DEL"

                        End If
                        rstSC.Close

                    Case "6"
                         rstSC.Open "select * from qryMaterial_Class_SC_Values where matn = " & rstBom.Fields("material").Value & " and [Supply Chain] = 'DIRAMAR'", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                         If Not rstSC.EOF Then
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "X"

                         Else
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "DEL"

                         End If
                         rstSC.Close

                     Case "7"
                        'rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "COPACK"
                        rstSC.Open "select * from qryMaterial_Class_SC_Values where matn = " & rstBom.Fields("material").Value & " and [Supply Chain] = 'COPACK'", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                        If Not rstSC.EOF Then
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "X"
                        Else
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "DEL"


                        End If
                        rstSC.Close

                    Case "8"
                        'rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "YUBE"
                        rstSC.Open "select * from qryMaterial_Class_SC_Values where matn = " & rstBom.Fields("material").Value & " and [Supply Chain] = 'YUBE'", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                        If Not rstSC.EOF Then
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "X"
                        Else
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "DEL"


                        End If
                        rstSC.Close

                    Case "9"
                        'rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "POLAND"
                        rstSC.Open "select * from qryMaterial_Class_SC_Values where matn = " & rstBom.Fields("material").Value & " and [Supply Chain] = 'POLAND'", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
                        If Not rstSC.EOF Then
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "X"
                        Else
                            rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "DEL"


                        End If
                        rstSC.Close

                    Case Else
                        rstIN.Fields("BOM_found").Value = "DEL"

                End Select


                rstIN.Update

                rstBom.MoveNext

            Loop

        End If 
        rstBom.Close
    rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "delete from tblPacking_private_label_base where BOM_Found = 'DEL'"
End function
```

The strange thing is it gives the error twice, I click debug, the third time it runs perfectly fine.

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: One thing to try: do a full [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271) -- follow these steps to the letter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately this didn't work

Comment: `where val(Component) =` this looks fishy. You should never have to use `Val()` like this. Try removing it.

Comment: FYI `val()` only returns a numeric value from a string, such as `123 Fake Street` returning `123`. `val(Component)` will return `0`

Comment: When it fails the first time, what are the values in each side of the criteria?   val(Component) = " & rst.Fields("matnr").Value

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the val(component) = ... and it did the trick.
Thanks alot for the help!