# MS-Access VBA: Passing variable from one form to another giving a run-time error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a form `frm_New_Datasheet` to enter datasheets from volunteers into a database I'm making. For the volunteer id text box `txt_Vol_ID` I've got two buttons to either search for an existing volunteer or add a new one, each opening a respective form. I want the `Vol_ID` from `frm_Volunteers` to get passed back to `frm_New_Datasheet` once I add a new volunteer.

To do this, I added the following code to my volunteer form:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    If Not IsNull(Me.vol_Vol_ID) Then
        Dim volVal As Double
        volVal = Me.vol_Vol_ID
        Forms!frm_New_Datasheet!txt_Vol_ID.Value = volVal
    End If

End Sub
```

And it worked perfectly. Then I tried creating my 'Search for Volunteers' form, added the same code to it, but now I get the following error on both:

> Run-time error -2146500594 (800f000e):
>   Method 'Item' of object 'Forms' failed

The debugger is highlighting the line where I set the `.Value = volVal` so I've looked for other ways to call that text box but no luck yet. I've tried

```
Forms([frm_New_Datasheet]).[txt_Vol_ID] = volVal`
```

but that gives me a different error:

> Run-time error '2465':
>   Microsoft Access can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression

I'm pretty lost on this because I think I'm calling the other form's text box properly, and when I search for the first run-time error the best advice I've found is "Sometimes VBA is buggy and try restarting" which hasn't helped. So far this is the best idea I've had to pass the value from one form to another. If there's another place I can drop this code or another way to skin this cat I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest doing Compact&Repair and a full [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271).

Comment: Pretty sure I followed those instructions correctly but still no dice. Thanks for the link to that process, though, a good method to have at hand.

Comment: That first error message suggests Access does not see a form named *"frm_New_Datasheet"* in the `Forms` collection.  Check which form names Access sees.  Paste this line of code into the Immediate window and press Enter: `for each f in forms : ? f.name : next`  Is *"frm_New_Datasheet"* listed there?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm pretty new to VBA/Access but I can't seem to get your suggested code to do anything. I enter it into the Immediate window and hit enter but it just goes to a new line and nothing happens. Tried following the OP here: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/829700-list-all-forms-database and I get an "Invalid in Immediate Pane" Compile error.

Comment: Open some other form, then run the code I suggested again. Is the name of the other form listed?

Comment: Ah, now it's working. Only listing `frm_Volunteers`, any idea why my other form isn't being seen? It's listed in the side pane of the VBA editor right above frm_Volunteers.

Comment: OK.  So you believe `frm_New_Datasheet` is open, but Access does not see it in the `Forms` collection.  Is `frm_New_Datasheet` a subform contained by `frm_Volunteers`?  `Forms` contains open top-level forms, not subforms.

Comment: Turned out it wasn't still open when I ran it, so I listed my forms again and got the same run-time error as originally. I copied frm_New_Datasheet as frm_New_New_Datasheet and, lo and behold, it's all working as expected again. I've still got no clue what was wrong with my original form but at least now I can move forward. Thanks a ton for helping me troubleshoot this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this actually counts as an answer but after HansUp helped me through with some trouble shooting in the comments above I just copied the form that wasn't being found (still not sure why), pasted it with a new name, and deleted the original form. After that everything is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should check form/control names more carefully and make sure that the form `frm_New_Datasheet` is open.

Here is the correct variant for referring using Forms collection by form name:

```
Forms("frm_New_Datasheet").txt_Vol_ID = volVal
```

Comment: But that's basically the same as `Forms!frm_New_Datasheet!txt_Vol_ID.Value = volVal`.

Comment: Yes, the same and this variant worked well, so the problem is with not opened form or control name. The second variant is not correct at all, I just corrected it. Secons variant may give more relevant error message

Comment: I changed my second variant to quotes but it just gave me the same Run-time (-2146500594 (800f000e)) as the first variant now. Since I'm launching the second form from the first I'd assume it's already opened?