# How is the size of the .accdb file determined in the US? UK?

Tags: ms-access

I have a large MS Access application, 45,000+ lines of VBA code that runs our shop floor, shipping and serial inventory mfg. processes.  This app employs 50+ SQL Server tables stored on local servers as well as in the cloud. It has one small MS Access table embedded, used to store locality info as it is running at multiple sites in the US and UK.  ~250 users execute a fresh copy of the .accdb file copied down to their own PCs at execution time. (Each user is running standalone, whilst accessing the shared SQL data for that organization.)

The size of the .accdb file varies significantly, as illustrated below.  My question is why?  Below doesn't make any sense me.

- Typical size as deployed in the US production:               115 mb
- Size during development & test:                              145-255 mb
  (Prior to command line compacting.  Not a concern, but I'm including anyway as a data point.)
- Typical size as deployed in UK production:                    26 mb
  (After copying across via TeamViewer and running locally in the UK so the app can configure its local ODBC connections.)
- Typical size if US .accdb file is copied from US to US:       115 mb
  (After copying on the same PC, or PC to PC, or via TeamViewer.  It seems the size only shrinks if copying from the US to UK.)
- Size in US if UK version is copied back to the US:            26 mb
- Size after opening the UK version just once in the US:        107 mb

Irrespective of copy operations above, the app works the same in all respects.  (No corruption.)

I can't find anything in or our MS Office, network or local desktop configuration options in the US or UK that might explain the metrics above, which I've been seeing since UK deployment was deployed last June.

Seems like a really naive question, but is Microsoft somehow managing MS Access memory differently in the US and UK deployments of the 64 bit version of MS Access Office 365?

The reason I ask is that the .accdb file is copied to desktops very often. So reducing the file size from 115 mb to 26 mb in the US would be very beneficial.

/end/

Comment: That's weird. I have two very similar systems developed for UK and US databases, and they do differ in size 70Mb and 80Mb but there are sufficient structure differences to accommodate that. 
Have you tried a full Decompile on the US version ? That will often remove "legacy artifacts" but it's a pretty big difference.

Comment: As Minty wrote: only after a full [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271) and the final Compact&Repair do you have the "actual" size of the frontend. These are the numbers to compare.

Comment: I see minor oddities quite often like after I run a compact\repair on an empty DB and deploy it the size shrinks after data is put in to the tables. How populated tables could be smaller than empty tables, I don't know. Access is a very strange beast.

Answer (score 0):

You database size seems a bit large for the given number of lines and forms.

I have 80,000 lines of code, 351 forms, 234 reports, and 600 linked tables (to several SQL backbends).

After a de-compile, then C + R, the total size is 76.5 Megs.

Remember, when you do a decompile, you MUST hold down the shift key and NOT let any start up code done. Right after I do a decompile, then I exit.

Now Re-launch (again, hold down shift key, NO start-up code allowed to run). At this point, you do a C + R (and again, shift key to prevent any start-up code). And again, exit.

As noted, this results in a front end of 76.5 Megs.

If I jump into VBA, and go debug-compile to compile all the VBA code, then exit, the size becomes 86.1 Megs.

So, often the overall size is effected by imbedded graphics. You could check out the image gallery to see what’s imbedded.

It is hard to say and tell if your size is not normal. It is within the “range” for the numbers you quoted, but I seem to have a lot more code, lot more forms/reports, and the size I see is not a whole lot larger than the numbers you are quoting here.

I think the size issue is often effected by imbedded graphics.

The other option I would check is if row locking is turned on. While you are using linked tables, I would turn off “row” locking feature, as that feature when on forces JET (ACE) data engine to expand all data operations to the size of one data page, and that cases HUGE bloat.

So check the row locking feature.

Comment: Row locking is off.  In latest version of Office 365 there is a setting for built in compact on exit.  When in dev mode I run every time automatically. When deployed that's shut off by the app to save time as the loadset is never used again anyway.  Just to be safe, I do a compact at the command line via a short VB script at deployment time.  I'm going to try your very helpful tips concerning manual compact and will reply again.

Comment: No joy.  Are you running 32 bit or 64 bit?  I'm 64 bit which is "bulky".  BTW, I have  454 forms, 85 reports (most reporting is BI) and about 400 queries.  Going to be moving those to SQL soon to improve performance.

Comment: Ok, given the number of forms you have then accDB sizes seem about right. As for the C+R tips? They are in regards to a de-compile. So that exit + enter dance I speak of and suggest is in regards to the decompile. (I assume you have a shortcut setup to de-compile - have you tested using de-compile???). While my example has DOUBLE the lines of code you note, you do have more forms, so in this light, the actual accDB file size(s) you speak of seem about right. However that "really" big difference in size between regions is perplexing.

Comment: I should also point out that the row locking feature is set in the Access client, and NOT the application. This setting does NOT follow the application settings, and has to be set in the Access client application. You can set the row locking feature on startup, but if it was turned on, then the change in setting will not take effect until Access is exited, and then re-launched. Since the "main" bulk of data is not in the local database, then this issue is not a huge one in terms of bloat due to data, but it can also effect the amount of bloat you see when just developing.

Comment: Right, row locking is set off in client setting when our PCs are deployed, alone with other things like confirming deletes, etc..  All forms but a couple also don't lock.  This is all very helpful but my question still is this: what happens to explain that when I copy from US to UK and app size is divided by about 4.  Then, if I copy back to the US the app is still the same size as in the UK.  I can run the smaller sized app OK in the UK and US.  But if I change  1 line of code in the US it goes back to almost as big as (but not quite) before the initial copy to the UK & BTW, only in the US.

Comment: Bloating occurrence does not matter if do not use ANY locking in ANY place in the application. The row lock tells the database engine to EXPAND ALL records to a size of database a page. This occurs regardless of the application locking settings are used or not. A simple edit will cause expansion when turned on. A simple loop to edit some rows for a 6 meg database causes NO bloat with the feature turned off. When turned on, same simple edit loop (without any lockng) causes the file to bloat to 126 megs (so 120 meg of bloat occurs with the feature turned on - not that you use ANY locking at all.

Comment: Yikes!  VERY helpful.  Thank you.  I'll look into this and reply again.  The couple times I locked were judgement calls.  This new clearly suggests a different call.

Comment: There were 5 locks.  Eliminated all but one.  Unfortunately this last one is needed as it is for a one record table that stores the next shop order number to be assigned.  The code that opens new shop orders is executed by many different users. This code uses a hidden form with "lock edited record" as means to make it happen.  Can't think of any way around this as duplicate shop order numbers are verboten.

Comment: Does not matter if you don't use locking in ANY place at all. That open with row locking forces Access to ALWAYS expand any and all records - even if you are NOT using any kind of locking at all. It is a on/off setting and has ZERO to do with you actually using locks. Access has page locking, but not true row locking. Turning this feature on thus "fakes" row locking since every bit of data you touch is now expanded to the size of one database page. Of course since your tables are linked, then none of the bloat or locking features apply or matter when using a server database.

Comment: Why this feature MIGHT apply to you is in two cases. #1 - you have a lot of local tables - they might be expanded with this feature one. #2 - Access as the development tool uses the JET/ACE data engine to store all kinds of objects - if those objects are expanded, then that explains the different sizes you are seeing. It might be that "region" version is NOT your issue here. (and this locking issue might not be your issue anyway). As noted this feature only going to effect local data tables, or linked tables to a access back end - does NOT apply nor effect server based tables.