# How to decompile an Access database?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Any time I try to decompile my access DB it says:

> ‘MSACCESS.EXE’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Here is the command I am using to decompile my DB:
`C:\Program files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE /decompile`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need quotes around the path with spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one decompile and recompile a database application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application)

Comment: Like this: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" /decompile`.

Comment: I did as you said, and I am still getting the same error

Comment: On a proper installation, `MSACCESS.EXE /decompile` should suffice. If it doesn't, consider running the Office installer in repair mode to make sure MSACCESS.EXE is registered properly.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @Gustav was right when I put the double quotes around the path it worked, but it is just not solving my problem

Comment: which is "Id is not an index in this table". I thought decompile will solve the problem, but it is not.

Comment: That sounds more like a table error. Decompile can't help on that. Try Compact & Repair, or create a new database and import all objects from the old.

Comment: I tried Compact and Repair that didn't work. I created a new DB and tried to export the objects, but I was only able to export the tables Not the forms nor the reports.

Comment: This error is driving me nuts

Comment: The error prevents me from exporting the forms or the reports

Comment: I tried importing all the objects, but this option is not working on the forms or the reports either. it still gives me the error message "id is not an index in this table" when I click OK on the last step of the import or export dialog box.

Comment: You should close this question and open a new one with the real problem clearly defined.