# Access SQL can't find table when it exists

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have new error `Error 3078: The Microsoft Access engine cannot find the table 'tbl_Parameters'....`  I have not made any changes in this area of the cod. The same error occurs on a previous version of the application where I did not make any changes at all.

The table `tbl_Parameters` is local to the database.  I have the same problem with another table that is in a linked database.  The application is able access all the other 20+ tables without any errors.

Here is the code that fails.

```
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 PARAMETER_VALUE FROM tbl_Parameters WHERE PARAMETER_NAME _ ='DATE_LAST_PN_FILE';"  
Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)  
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenForwardOnly)
```

I run the query`SELECT TOP 1 PARAMETER_VALUE FROM tbl_Parameters WHERE PARAMETER_NAME = 'DATE_LAST_PN_FILE';` in the query editor and it runs fine.

Any help to solve this problem is appreciated.

Comment: `WHERE PARAMETER_NAME _ =` - remove that trailing underscore.

Comment: And try Compact&Repair + [Decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271)

Comment: Are you sure `DBEngine(0)(0) ` is the database you want? Generally, we use `CurrentDb` to avoid trouble when multiple databases are open.