# Access "too few parameters" or crash but only before compact and repair

Tags: vba, ms-access

Bit of an odd one here, essentially I have a VBA function in Microsoft Access that takes two arguments provided and cuts the data from the existing table to a temp table, and then compares this to the latest data from an external an SQL database and then reappends the updated information.

This has worked fine for years, and has never been touched, until recently, everytime I run the function I get an error:

> Run-time error '-2147217904(8004e10)':
> Too few parameters. Expected 2.

However, if I manually compact and repair, or recompile the database, this error goes away and the function completes as normal. But only for that session, currently the staff that use this function have to compact and repair everytime they open the Acces front end to make the function complete. Compact and repair on close does not work.

The code is below, but again, it has worked as-is for year with no changes and works after a C&R.

```
Function AccCompleteOrder(LabID As String, OrderID As String) As Boolean
  
  Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
  Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rstPackageCount As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim rstTmpData As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim rstRealData As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim params() As Variant

  'set up cmd and query parameters
  params = Array(LabID, OrderID)
  Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
  cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
  
  'check that packages have been added to the order in genophyle
  cmd.CommandText = "qryAccCheckPackagesAdded"
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.Parameters.Refresh
  Set rstPackageCount = cmd.Execute(, params)
  
  If (rstPackageCount("packageCount") = 0) Then
    AccCompleteOrder = False
    Exit Function
  End If
  
  'Move dummy records to Temp table
  If TableExists("tmpTblAccDeletion") Then
      DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tmpTblAccDeletion"
  End If
  cmd.CommandText = "qryAccMoveToTemp"
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.Parameters.Refresh
  cmd.Execute , params
  
  'delete old lines from table
  cmd.CommandText = "qryAccDeleteFromWIL"
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.Parameters.Refresh
  cmd.Execute , params
  
  'Append real data from Genophyle orders
  cmd.CommandText = "qryAccAppendfrmGenophyle"
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.Parameters.Refresh
  cmd.Execute , params
  
  'Get tempData recordset
  cmd.CommandText = "qryAccSelectTmpData"
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.Parameters.Refresh
  Set rstTmpData = cmd.Execute
  
  'Get real Data (from WIL) dataset
  cmd.CommandText = "qryAccSelectRealData"
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.Parameters.Refresh
  
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("LabID", adChar, , 10, LabID)
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("OrderID", adBigInt, , 10, OrderID)
  
  rstRealData.Open cmd, , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
  Do While Not rstRealData.EOF
    rstRealData("Country") = rstTmpData("Country")
    Do While Not rstTmpData.EOF
      If (rstRealData.Fields("Platform") = rstTmpData.Fields("Platform")) Then
        For i = 0 To rstRealData.Fields.Count - 1
          If (IsNull(rstRealData.Fields(i)) Or rstRealData.Fields(i) = 0) Then
            rstRealData.Fields(i) = rstTmpData.Fields(i)
          End If
        Next
      End If
      rstTmpData.MoveNext
    Loop
    rstTmpData.MoveFirst
    rstRealData.Update
    rstRealData.MoveNext
  Loop

  rstRealData.Close
  
  'update the accessioning check table
  cmd.CommandText = "qryAccUpdateAccessioningCheckOrderComplete"
  cmd.Parameters.Refresh
  
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("LabID", adChar, , 10, LabID)
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("OrderID", adBigInt, , 10, OrderID)
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("ComDate", adChar, , 50, Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss"))
  cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("ComCheck", adBoolean, , , True)
  
  cmd.Execute
  
  AccCompleteOrder = True
  
End Function
```

The debugger indicates the error is when it reaches the line

```
rstRealData.Open cmd, , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

This has me stumped.

Comment: A full [Decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271) could help. Follow these steps to the letter.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it did not work, however I did seem to figure out how to make it work/fail consistently. If I do the steps above, decompile/compact/recompile THEN run the in-built analyze performance program in the ribbon, it seems to work. When closing the database, it seems to lose that data and then no longer works. Very confusing. Perhaps just corrupted overall?