# MS-Access problem with database when I try to back up or Compact & Repair

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS-Access database I have used for 10+ years and I daily Compact & Repair and then BackUp.
Today it failed saying 'You attempted to open a database that is already opened.... etc..'.
So, tried a backup - same message, couldn't even close MS-Access - had to delete via Task Manager.
Tried a reboot, same result.
Tried opening several of my daily backups but they all gave the same result.
Went to Settings/Apps and Repaired 365.
Tried again, same result.
Can anyone suggest anything please?

Comment: Does laccdb get removed when db closed by whatever means?

Comment: If you are running the latest update, _Version 2201 (Build 14827.20158 Click and run)_, this is a new bug reported from several sources. Only remedy currently, is to revert to the previous version.

Comment: Hi June7 - unfortunately not. I have to remove manually because i had to kill the Access task

Comment: Hi Gustav, I'm on 365 so not sure how I can revert - when i had standalone MS-Access I did this previously when they let a SQL issue slip into the release - 2 years ago? Would love to revert to old version.

Comment: Try the guide from Daniel: [Microsoft Office 365 – Uninstall an Update](https://www.devhut.net/microsoft-office-uninstall-an-update/).

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70916653/office-365-version-2201-leaves-ghost-background-processes-in-task-manager-after