# Set X = Form.Recordset gives Run time error ‘13’: (Type mismatch)

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset, type-mismatch

In Access VBA I have written a routine (subform Click event) to display in a text box on the main form the contents of a field in the selected row of the subform, when the user clicks on a row in a subform.

I created a simple form/subform application to test the code and it works perfectly.  However, when I port this code into the production application I am updating, I get error 13.  My  debug code shows that both variables (MyRsMF and MyFormMF.Recordset) are type 9 (Object).  I have reduced my routine’s code to the sample below.
I accept that there is a difference between my test application environment and my production app.  However, I have run out ideas and would be grateful for any suggestions as to how I can find the difference(s).

I am working with W10 and Access 365.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Form_Click()
    '
    Dim MyFormMF As Form
    Dim MyRsMF As Recordset
    
    '  Get the Form's recordset
    Set MyFormMF = Forms.TB.Form
    Debug.Print VarType(MyRsMF) & vbTab & VarType(MyFormMF.Recordset)
    Set MyRsMF = MyFormMF.Recordset            <<----<<<  Error 13 occurs here
    
    Set MyFormMF = Nothing
    Set MyRsMF = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you still get the error if you explicitly declare the recordset type for `MyRsMF` like this? `Dim MyRsMF As DAO.Recordset`

Comment: Hi HansUp.  Thanks for the interest.  No.  That gives me a different error: 'User-defined data type not defined'.  I thought that I might have to include the 'Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object library' even though it is not included in my test app.  When I tried that I got an error trying to load the DLL.  Back to you.

Comment: DAO 3.6 is for the older MDB database format. If your database is ACCDB format, you should have a reference for 'Microsoft Office <version> Access database engine Object Library' instead. What combination of database format and library reference are you using?

Comment: I have a linked database (ACCDB + MDB) and the Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine Object Library.

Comment: The full edit:  I have a linked database (ACCDB + MDB) and the Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine Object Library.  Also, a bit of background.  The app is a membership/library app for our German club here in Canberra and started life about 20 years ago, so has been through many versions of Access.  I am retired and have been maintaining it for several years.

Comment: Please check whether I understand the details.  You have an ACCDB database which contains the form and VBA code you showed us.  That database has the Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine Object Library reference checked.  When you change the declaration as I suggested ... `Dim MyRsMF As DAO.Recordset` ... than line triggers the compile error 'User-defined data type not defined'.  Is that all correct?

Comment: If yes, test that code in a new ACCDB.  If it works there, your older ACCDB may be corrupt and [decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3266542/77335) might fix it.

Comment: Hi Hans.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I needed someone to point out the (in hindsight) bleeding obvious.  Recreating the access files was an interesting process and has solved this issue.
One possible cause was the inheritance of an incompatibility between the tables/relations ship file in MDB (pre 2006) format and the Access 365 product.  Maybe, maybe not.
Whatever the cause the recreated tables file in is now in the current ACCDB format and works.