# VBA Folder Picker No longer works

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have always run this code to retrieve the file path of the folder I select. But for some reason now I am getting a subscript out of range error now.

```
Public Function GetFolder()

Dim objFileDialog As Office.FileDialog
    Set objFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With objFileDialog
        .InitialFileName = "G:\"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .ButtonName = "Folder Picker"
        .Title = "Folder Picker"
        If (.Show > 0) Then
        End If
        If (.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
            GetFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Running the code and expecting to retrieve a file path string.

Comment: Works fine here, so run a _Compact & Repair_.

Comment: Hi, I Compact & Repair and still get a subscript out of range error still.

Comment: Can you check your VBA project has a reference to 'Microsoft Office NN.N Object Library' (where NN.N is likely 16.0)

Comment: Hi John, the reference library is exactly what you described.

Comment: Rewrite the function. No copy-paste.

Comment: Which line triggers the error? -- Also, try a full [Decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271).

Comment: I wrote the code out again without copy and paste and recompiled the code.         
 The line If (.Show > 0)  will open the window to selected the folder and after selected the folder it will show the subscript error message. Which is weird because This code been working for months and now has this issue?

Comment: @Andre asked you yesterday, Which line triggers the error?
I don't expect that to be the line with .SelectedItems(1). Do you store the result of GetFolder() in an array, and did you change "Option Base" recently?

Comment: The `If (.Show > 0) Then    End If` part doesn't do anything, did you omit something there? Put a breakpoint there and then step debug, to see which line causes the error. See [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Trying to print `.SelectedItems(0)` or `.SelectedItems(2)` triggers an `Invalid procedure call or argument` error, so a wrong index here doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Could you try this - create a new Database, add a (standard) Module and add your `GetFolder()` function with no other code ... run the function (ie F5) and see if it works okay?