# Deleting tabs from a TabControl with VBA /MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, tabcontrol

Using this code I am trying to use my code to delete Tabs form a main "Tab", but I am missing the correct method somehow

```
`Private Sub DeleteAlltabs(frm As Object)

Dim tabCtrl As TabControl

    Set tabCtrl = frm.Controls("Tab")
    
    If Not tabCtrl Is Nothing Then
        For i = tabCtrl.Pages.count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            tabCtrl.Pages(i).Remove
        Next i

    End If
End Sub`
```

I even tried it with a while wend, and a slightly different code, but something seemingly so simple is not working:

```
If Not tabCtrl Is Nothing Then
        While tabCtrl.Pages.count > 0            
            tabCtrl.Pages.Remove tabCtrl.Pages(tabCtrl.Pages.count - 1)
        Wend
End If
```

my components are:

1. Visual Basic for Applications
2. Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
3. OLE Automation
4. Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database engine Object Library

I tried both codes, and wanted it to delete the tabs, but it gave me a syntax error on both accords.

Comment: Is the form opened in [Design View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.pages.remove#remarks)?

Comment: In the first code snippet, the line `tabCtrl.Pages(i).Remove` doesn't seem correct, `tabCtrl.Pages(i)` returns the `Page` object which doesn't have `Remove` method. Try `tabCtrl.Pages.Remove(i)`

Comment: What should it be sir?

Comment: In the second code snipped, try appending `.PageIndex` to make it `tabCtrl.Pages.Remove tabCtrl.Pages(tabCtrl.Pages.count - 1).PageIndex` as the `Remove` method actually expects page index.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: Did you know there is a possibility to hide the relevant tabs by using : Me.tabControl.Pages(0).Visible = False ? when you use this when you load the form, there is no need to delete anything.

Comment: The creation of the tabs will occur dynamically. The number of tabs and their names and content is to be created dynamically. So before this occurs I need to delete the tabs.

Comment: @bilal tabCtrl.Pages.Remove tabCtrl.Pages(tabCtrl.Pages.count - 1).PageIndex as the Remove doesn't work. I get a compiling error, as the remove method or data object is not found.

Comment: @bilal: tabCtrl.Pages.Remove(i) only send to have the problem that I get an error saying that I need to be in a development view to delete or create a controller.. so does that mean I can't do that dynamically?

Comment: Or is there a trick to make it seem like I'm in a development mode?

Comment: No trick. Form must be in Design View - as noted in the first comment above. You can set visibility and/or change captions. At least one tab must remain visible.

Comment: To open your form in Design View: `DoCmd.OpenForm "YourFormName", acDesign`  If the form was already open in Form View, that will switch it to Design View without complaining.

Comment: Oh fantastic, so I could then open it in design view, perform the dynamic alterations to the tabs, and then open it in normal view? That would be perfect.

Comment: But now I get an error 2467 using the "set tabctrl = frm.controls("name")"

Comment: @HansUp Shall I maybe open a new thread?

Comment: @KingsleyObeng I don't see a benefit from a new thread.  What is the status of `frm` when you get that error?  Does `Debug.Print frm.Name` give you the same error at that point?

Comment: Yes, it does. Exactly the same error

Comment: The same as the first code above, just that before the set tabctrl, I have the open form. acDesign line in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Bilel explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78189255/deleting-tabs-from-a-tabcontrol-with-vba-ms-access#comment137845815_78189255), `tabCtrl.Pages(i)` refers to one `Page` in the tab control's `Pages` collection and a `Page` object does not have a `Remove` method.

So you must use `Pages.Remove` instead.  If you want to target a specific page based on its index, you can do this:

```vb
tabCtrl.Pages.Remove i
```

Or if you omit the index, the last page will be removed:

```vb
tabCtrl.Pages.Remove
```

I think the second version simplifies the task.  Here is the code I tested:

```vb
Public Sub DeleteAlltabs(frm As Form)
    Dim tabCtrl As TabControl
    Dim i As Long

    Set tabCtrl = frm.Controls("TabCtl0") ' I changed the name of the tab control
    For i = 1 To tabCtrl.Pages.Count
        tabCtrl.Pages.Remove
    Next i
End Sub
```

Another issue is that *"You can remove a Page object from the Pages collection of a tab control only when the form is in Design view.*" (see [Pages.Remove method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.pages.remove#remarks))

So I opened the form in Design View before calling the modified subroutine:

```vb
Public Sub calling_code()
    Const cstrForm As String = "Form13"
    DoCmd.OpenForm cstrForm, acDesign
    DeleteAlltabs Forms(cstrForm)
    DoCmd.Close acForm, cstrForm, acSaveYes
End Sub
```

Comment: It crashes, on occasion, before saving..but it does it! Do you know how I can avoid the crashes? By crash, I mean the Application completely closes..

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain the crashes.  I didn't encounter any problems in my testing.

Comment: If you create a new database and export the relevant form(s) and code to it, does that one also crash?  If no, perhaps your problem database is corrupt.  In that case, try [decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application).

Comment: one last question, how do I remove the actual "TabCtl0"?? after all its easier to control the tab control, if I use a "set" to "createControt"..then I can add all my other features dnamically onto the newly created tab ctrl.

Comment: [Application.DeleteControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.deletecontrol) looks useful to me.

Comment: thanks ever so much..and really the last one now:) if I wanted to add a tab to the existing tab control, I noticed I can't just say tabcrtl.pages.add(), can I ? How do I go about it? That is reallly it then :) thanks again

Comment: I don't know how to do that.